# Questions about PayFlow Pro API and where download latest release? (paypal_base.dll, Version 5.6.65.1, Runtime v1.1.4322)

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

I'm constantly confused with PayPal (x.com vs. developer.paypal.com, API names, etc.) and need help locating the latest API that I'm currently using in my project.  I have a Visual Studio 2010 C# reference to this DLL:

> paypal_base (Properties: version 5.6.65.1, Runtime Version: v1.1.4322)

Questions:

Q1. What is URL of latest download?

Q2. I downloaded payflow_dotnet_setup_v4.33.zip and I'm reading "PayPal Payflow SDK for .NET Developer's Guide), BUT there is NO MENTION of any of the current calls I'm already using that look like this.  Why?

> ```
>         DoCaptureRequestType pp_request = new DoCaptureRequestType();
>         pp_request.AuthorizationID = authorizationId;
>         return (DoCaptureResponseType)caller.Call("DoCapture", pp_request);
> ```

Q3. Is this API deprecated in liu of REST API?

I'm SO confused.

Pete

Comment: So that I can provide the correct information, are you trying to use Payflow's or PayPal's API.  What type of an account do you have?  When you log into your account, do you go to www.paypal.com and log in with an email address, or do you go to manager.paypal.com and log in with partner, login, user, password?

Comment: Can you tell me given the API call above?  That's part of the confusion and I don't know.  I think it's Payflow Pro API from several years ago.  Yes, I ago to www.paypal.com and log in with an email address.

Comment: These are the using statements: using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.soap.api;
using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;   The API included a PayPalAPI.cs file (I think) where I authenticate by instantiating this object: profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile(); and setting the APISignature property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X.com was the home of the developer site for PayPal, but it is being migrated over to [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com).  Eventually everything you need for Payflow, PayPal, and etc to get started processing payments will be found on [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com).  You can find the most recent version of the [PayPal SDK's here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/).  The REST API's are newer API's  which can be used as well, however they are still new and they are not supported for every country yet and not all of the features are available yet.

Comment: Can you ascertain which API I'm using given the information I've provided?

Comment: I downloaded payflow_dotnet_setup_v4.33.zip yet there is no mention of anything of the objects I'm using in my existing code.  Really confused.